# Type of CLOCKS_PER_SEC

Tags: c++, time, types

What datatype is CLOCKS_PER_SEC typically represented as?  `long unsigned int`?  `clock_t`?  Does it vary from implementation to implementation?

I ask because I use `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` in a return value, and I want to make sure I use the most appropriate type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that the C standard promises is that `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is a constant expression with the type `clock_t` which must be an arithmetic type (could be an integer or a floating type).

(C99 7.23 Date and time `<time.h>`)

I think that `clock_t` is typically a `long`, but I wouldn't bet my life that I'm right.

My usually trusty Harbison & Steele (3rd ed) suggests casting `clock_t` to `double` for use in your programs so your code can work regardless of the actual `clock_t` type (18.1 CLOCK, CLOCK_T, CLOCKS_PER_SEC, TIMES):

> Here is how the `clock` function can
>   be used to time an ANSI C program:
>
> ```
> #include <time.h>
> clock_t start, finish, duration;
> start = clock();
> process();
> finish = clock();
> printf("process() took %f seconds to execute\n", 
>          ((double) (finish - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );
> ```
>
> Note how the cast to type `double`
>   allows `clock_t` and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`
>   to be either floating-point or
>   integral.

You might consider whether this would work for your purposes.

Comment: And now I notice that this is the same advice from the glibc manual that Tomalak mentions in his answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129029/type-of-clocks-per-sec/6129078#6129078)

Comment: C99 is not relevant. This question is about C++, and there is no relationship between the two.

Comment: I don't see where in C standard it requires `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to be a *constant* expression. C99 refers to it as an "expression of type clock_t", seemingly deliberately omitting the term "constant". The matter popped up in different context: whether `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` should be usable under `#if`. The standard requires object-like macros that qualify as integer constant expressions to be usable under `#if`. But AFAIK `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` does not qualify and cannot be used under `#if` in general case.

Comment: My copy of C99 (which I imagine was my source at the time of the answer) says "expands to a constant expression with type `clock_t`".  My copy of C11 omits the word "constant". Whether or not it's constant, it still can't be portably used in a preprocessor expression (as you state in the answer to the related question) because it isn't necessarily an integral type.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Yes, the original C99 says "constant". In C99 TC2 that word is gone already.

Comment: @Michael Burr: I'd guess that two requirements clash with each other here: 1) usability under `#if`, which precludes casts, 2) must have type `clock_t`, which generarly requires a cast.

Answer (score 3):

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is a macro, that usually expands to a literal.

The [glibc manual](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_19.html) says:

> In the GNU system, clock_t is
>   equivalent to long int and
>   CLOCKS_PER_SEC is an integer value.
>   But in other systems, both clock_t and
>   the type of the macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC
>   can be either integer or
>   floating-point types. Casting
>   processor time values to double, as in
>   the example above, makes sure that
>   operations such as arithmetic and
>   printing work properly and
>   consistently no matter what the
>   underlying representation is.

Answer (score 1):

CLOCK_PER_SEC is actually specified by POSIX as part of the [time.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html) header.

That says it's a clock_t as described by [sys/types.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html).

That in turn says:

> time_t and clock_t shall be integer or
>   real-floating types.

So all you can assume in portable code is that it is some integral or floating point type.  If you just need to declare a variable to store the value, declare it as "clock_t".